# Installing rmagick on osx 10.7.3 crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, osx-lion, rvm

I got a problem to install rmagick  on my osx 10.7.3 lion

- I used rvm
- Imagemagick is installed with homebrew
- gem install rmagick

  ```
  Fetching: rmagick-2.13.1.gem (100%)
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
      ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
          /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
  checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
  extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
  checking for clang... yes
  checking for Magick-config... yes
  checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
  checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
  checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
  necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
  details.  You may need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
      --with-opt-dir
      --with-opt-include
      --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
      --with-opt-lib
      --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
      --with-make-prog
      --without-make-prog
      --srcdir=.
      --curdir
      --ruby=/Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
  /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in
  ```

  `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
  (RuntimeError)
      You have to install development tools first.
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in`
  try_cpp'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in
  `block in have_header'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in`
  block in checking_for'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
  `block (2 levels) in postpone'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`
  open'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
  `block in postpone'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`
  open'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in
  `postpone'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in`
  checking_for'
          from /Users/lion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in
  `have_header'
          from extconf.rb:193:in`'
      Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for
  inspection.
      Results logged to /Users/lion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

Did anyone know what i can do to install rmagick  correctly?

Comment: whats in /Users/lion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out ? also `find /Users/lion/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ -name mkmf.log` and include the file - you can use gist.github.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that it's an upgrade and not pre-installed? I recently upgraded to Lion and had to do something like:

- uninstall xcode 3 (there's a non-destructive version of the uninstall script in case you care)
- install xcode 4 (free from the app store. big download).
- i use macports. i had to uninstall and reinstall them all. you'll need to do the same for homebrew if you haven't already.
- symlink or pass on command line the new gcc compiler (rmagick references gcc-4.2, but with xcode 4 it's called llvm-gcc-4.2. look up what that means if you're interested http://llvm.org/)

That pretty much sums up what I had to do. The clue was in the mkmf.log, so definitely look in there and update your question if my answer doesn't do it for you.